# Session-dependent apc variables

Tags: php, caching, apc

I want to store a sensible key in the data store (just to avoid storing it in standard sessions), but I want to make it accessible only to the session under which is stored.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The php memcached extension support storing sessions in memcached. Its something you will need to do anyway if you intent to scale past one server.

Comment: prefix the apc key with the session key?... anyway, what's the point? what's wrong with normal sessions?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan thanks, good idea. normal sessions are too unsecure.. I want to store an encryption key!

Comment: @sunrise What do you mean too unsecure? If an attacker can read session data its because he gained access to your system. So he can read APC stuff also.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan but apc stuff is in RAM (right?), session data in the disk.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan If you have only access to disk, you can't read ram.

Comment: @sunrise If you have access to the session files folder, trust me, you will have access to RAM too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, APC does not provide any access protection for stored variables (i.e. you have access to all stored variables from every session).

```
apc_store(session_id() . "_key", $value);
```

As already suggested, you can simply use the current session key as prefix. However, without further protection inside the application, the data would only be protected by the secrecy of the session key, but otherwise still be accessible from every session.

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest further protection?

Comment: There are several things to consider: (1) be careful with uses of `apc_fetch`. Ensure that it is only called with the correct prefix, and do not allow user-defined keys. (2) be even more careful with methods like `apc_cache_info` since these could reveal all current session keys (really big security problem!). (3) be sure that there is no accessible APC administration script lying on your server, since an attacker could use this to gain access to session keys. All in all, I believe you would be better off just using the `$SESSION` variable to store sensitive data...

Comment: I think I'll store sensitive data with APC but encrypted with a random key (stored in the session and generated at login time). What do you think of this solution?